# Make Rsync log its decision about hardlink creation

Tags: rsync

This is an [X-Post](https://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2023-May/033001.html) also asked on rsync mailing list.

I know it is a often discussed topic how rsync decide about using
hardlinks or copy a file. Even if content is unchanged problems are
often file permissions and owner ships. I know that.

Is it possible to configure rsync that way that it logs for each file
its decision about using a hardlink and if not why exactly it doesn't?

It would help me investigate problems with the hardlinks feature of rsync.

Comment: Use the `-vi` flags